# Spinner not showing correct data

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a custom adapter for the spinner. The spinner needs to show names from a list. The following is my code:

```
empNameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Salon");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String empName = jsonObject.getString("employeename");
                    String empId = jsonObject.getString("employee_id");
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("empId", empId);
                    hashMap.put("empName", empName);
                    empNameList.add(hashMap);
                }    
employeeAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.service_list, empNameList);
                    employeeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);
```

Here is my Adapter class:

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
HashMap<String, String> hashmap;

public EmployeeAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, arrayList);
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parrent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parrent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView42 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView42);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.pink));
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashmap = arrayList.get(position);
    System.out.println("empName = " + hashmap.get("empName"));
    holder.textView42.setText(hashmap.get("empName"));
    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView42;
}
```

Spinner is displaying the hashmap, not the names of empNameList. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: What do you mean `Spinner is displaying the hashmap not the names of the empNameList` ?

Comment: Spinner should show data like 
sunil
Sangeeta......
But it is showing 
{empName=sunil, empId=2}
{empName=sangeeta, empId=3}

Comment: Data like " : " - a colon?

Comment: edited the comment

Comment: First change _ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();_  to _ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;_. Also  change _hashmap = arrayList.get(position);_ to _HashMap<String, String> hashmap = arrayList.get(position);_ and comment this  _hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();_

Comment: `String value=(String)map.get(key);` if you pass the key it returns the value at that key

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal: How this possible because as in provided code you are using `holder.textView42.setText(hashmap.get("empName"));` means it will show only in row1 `sunil`,  in row2 `sangeeta`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K exactly. I have been using adapter classes for too long but never faced this issue.

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal: ok remove `hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();` line then check it

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132357/discussion-between--k-and-sid

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal: join chat room and show full adapter and class code in which parsing JSON

Comment: i don't have enough reputation on stackoverflow to talk there

Comment: I have removed hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
still not working

Comment: first print the size of _arrayList_

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal I know its completely irrelevant can u try by just commenting employeeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); line. Just for a test case

Comment: @Raghavendra I tried this too but the same thing and no error.

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal ρяσѕρєя already asked this question are u getting this whole line {empName=sunil, empId=2} {empName=sangeeta, empId=3} in 1 row of spinner or you have 2 rows in spinner?

Comment: 2 rows in a spinner

Comment: when I am selecting the item from the list, then it is giving correct data that is displaying ony the name of the employee in the spinner.

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal Can u try by adding toString() like  hashmap.get("empName").toString()? Another test case :)

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal one suggestion u can create a simple class with empId and empName and u can use setter and getter right?

Comment: @Raghvendra I have tried tostring(). I will try with getter and setter now.

Comment: @sakshiAgrawal if you create a class then override toString()  method in that class and return empName field of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the below method in your adapter class.

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    // View row = inflater.inflate(yourRowlayout, parent,false);
    TextView make = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewname);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    make.setText(arrayList.get(position).get("empName"));
    return view;
}
```

Comment: But now on selecting the item from the list, it is displaying hashmap in the spinner.